# Fermionizing the Gell-Mann Algebra

Tags: condensed-matter, group-theory, majorana-fermions

In condensed matter physics one often solves a spin Hamiltonian by transcribing the Pauli matrices into fermionic operators. For instance, in the Kitaev model you can introduce four Majorana modes for each lattice site, $\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3, \gamma,$ and obtain the correct algebra (up to a $Z_2$ factor) by making the substitutions

$\sigma_i = i\gamma_i \gamma$.

My question is, can we construct a similar representation of the generators of $SU(3)$ in terms of Majorana operators? That is, is there a solution to

$\lambda_i = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{m}  c_{ij_1...j_n} \gamma_{j_1}...\gamma_{j_n}$,

where $m$ is the number of Majorana's per site and the $\lambda_i$ are the Gell-Mann matrices?